# sql - import flat file with russian characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to import text file with english and russian characters into sql table .

when i'm using SQL import wizard:

if i define the columns as nvarchar i get 0xc020802e error,

while if i define it as varchar wizard work but all russian characters get changed. (e.g.  ׀³׀±׀´ׁ€׀°ׁƒ׀¿׀¾׀²)

what to do so it can read any language?

Comment: this link is for SSRS - it could help https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3119/import-utf8-unicode-special-characters-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: What is the actual error you get? "0xc020802e" doesn't tell us anything I'm afraid. Also, what is the encode of the file? If you try to import a unicode character into a `varchar` the resulting value is a `?`, so i think we're missing some steps here.

Comment: - Pre-execute (Error)
Messages
+Error 0xc020802e: Data Flow Task 1: The data type for "Source - C_EMAIL_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Column 0]" is DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
+Error 0xc0202094: Data Flow Task 1: Unable to retrieve column information from the flat file connection manager.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: +Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 1: Source - C_EMAIL_txt failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202094.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

+Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - Email" wrote 0 rows.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to change the collation on that column:

```
COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS_KS
```